# Converting HTML to Handlebars.js for Ghost Blog?

Tags: html, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I am very new to Handlebars.js, and after messing around with it for a couple hours the other night I was still a little confused. Basically, I was trying to take the look of http://html5up.net/aerial or https://medium.com/web-design-code and apply it to a custom theme for my ghost blog. Basically the look of a larger header picture with a blog base with posts underneath. I know this is a little vague, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way I have found when creating a Ghost theme is to take the free Casper theme and then modify it. Most of what you are looking to do is actually going to be done using just normal html/css/js with some handlebars mixed in. It can seem a little daunting (at least it was when I was doing my first one) with all the different handlebars commands, but honestly, you should just pretend like you are styling a normal website and just place the handlebars in. For example, take a look at this line from Casper:

```
 <h1 class="blog-title">{{@blog.title}}</h1>
```

It is just a normal header with a class that is styled by css, but instead of using the words for the title, just uses the handlebars call.

I am not entirely sure what you are looking for, so hopefully that helps.

Also, take a look at some free themes that you can grab, and maybe just do small tweaks to rather than building your own. I think these 2 might be similar to what you are looking for:

Preview - http://etheeks.com/

Download - https://github.com/viktorbezdek/ghostentista

and

Preview - http://decode-ghost-demo.scotthsmith.com/

Download - https://github.com/ScottSmith95/Decode-for-Ghost

(We compiled a list of every Ghost theme, you can check out other free themes here ([link](http://allghostthemes.com/tag/free/)) if you would like)

Good luck!!